# music.fadeout() appears to block sounds after fadeout complete

Tags: pygame

I'm having an issue with `music.fadeout()`. As I understand the music will be stopped after fadeout. Why then, does the below code allow for sounds to be played during fadeout but not after? The sounds are being mixed after fadeout; `mixer.get_busy()` returns True.

If I use `music.stop()` in place of `.fadeout()` the sounds play after the music has been stopped.

What am I missing here?

```
if not game_over:
        if music_on:
            pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(3000)
            #pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        music_on = False
```

In the meantime I've done this to resolve it:

```
if not game_over:
        if music_on:
            pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(3000)
            fadeout_start = ticks
            #pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        if fadeout_start + 3000 < ticks:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        music_on = False
```

*EDIT*

My specific issue Ted, which I don't think was covered in your answer(maybe I'm just being dense) is illustrated by the following:

When I start the Music (K_1), then stop it(K_2) and then play the sound object(K_5), mixer.get_busy is True and the sound audibly plays. However, if I repeat the above but fadeout the music(K_3) instead of stopping using K_2, mixer.get_busy is True but there is no audible sound.

Pydocs seem to suggest that the music is stopped after fadeout in the same way a simple music.stop() would.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
pygame.display.set_caption("Sound tester")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("theme.mid")
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("missile.wav")

playing = pygame.mixer.get_busy()



while True:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
            elif event.key == K_2:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            elif event.key == K_3:
                pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(2000)
            elif event.key == K_4:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            elif event.key == K_5:
                sound.play(-1)
            elif event.key == K_6:
                pygame.mixer.stop()

    music_playing = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()
    if music_playing:
        print("music playing")
    else:
        print("no music")

    sound_playing = pygame.mixer.get_busy()
    if sound_playing:
        print("Sound playing")
    else:
        print("no sound")
```

Comment: Fadeout does stop the music like `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` would after the fadeout time. I'm sorry but I cannot replicate your problem. When I fadeout the music I'm still able to play and stop the sound during the time the music is fading out.

Comment: Ah, drat. Thank you very much for the replies anyways.

Comment: If the music and sound file are something you're willing to share maybe we'd could test if there is a problem with those?

Comment: The same issue persists with different files. It's certainly an annoyance, but I've been able to code around it so it's not all bad. I'm new to coding so I've no ideas as to what else might cause an issue such as this.

Comment: Weird... It might be a bug of the version of pygame? Anyway good luck and hope you'll find the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The function `pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(3000)` will fade the volume for 3 seconds and then it will stop the music. After the music has been stopped you'll need to start it again. Your code should not play any music after fading out and must be because of some other logical error in your program (maybe you're setting `music_on = True` continuously?).

Here some code demonstrating how it works:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((250, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("music.wav")
playing = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(3000)
                print("Fading out")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                print("Play")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                print("Stop")
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    if playing != pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        playing = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()
        if playing:
            print("Music is playing")
        else:
            print("Music is not playing")
```

However, if by *"sound"* you mean a [pygame.mixer.Sound](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) object, it makes perfect sense. The [pygame.mixer.music](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) module handles the playback of music while [pygame.mixer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) handles sounds. These are separate (although closely tied). Stopping the `pygame.mixer` stops sounds while stopping `pygame.mixer.music` stops the music.

Experiment with the code below. Pressing 1 will start both the music and sound and immediately stop the `pygame.mixer`, and pressing 2 will start both the music and sound and immediately stop the `pygame.mixer.music`. You should here that they stop different things.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((250, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("music.wav")
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound.wav")

playing = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                sound.play(-1)
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                pygame.mixer.stop()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                sound.play(-1)
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
```